# how can fix "LateInitializationError: Field '_audioHandler' has not been initialized" in audio_service package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, audio-service

I'm working with the audio_service package in Flutter, and I'm trying to use the _audioHandler variable in my code. However, when I try to run the app, I get the following error message:

```
LateInitializationError: Field '_audioHandler' has not been initialized
```

I've tried initializing the AudioHandler before using it, but I still get the same error. I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

I run this player from **audioscreen.dart** like this :

```
await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) =>
    audio_play(),
   ),
);
```

audio_play(), function i call it from **audioPlay.dart**

The code in audioPlay.dart

https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/master/audio_service/example/lib/example_playlist.dart

I hope I have stated the problem clearly

I expected was that the AudioHandler would be properly initialized and that I would be able to use the _audioHandler variable without any issues. However, what actually happened was that I got a runtime error that prevented me from using this

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem, or provide guidance on how I can properly initialize the AudioHandler in my code?